# iOS- mimic system default tableView header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I want to mimic **programatically** the exact look of this header:
[image]

So far, my best try was:

```
UILabel* header = [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
header.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
header.textColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:86 green:92 blue:112 alpha:0.1];
header.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
header.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,0);
header.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
```

But it's looks like this:
[image]

Can someone please help me with the exact way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Norvegian guy has written a blog post about this a while ago: http://www.gersh.no/posts/view/default_styling_of_sections_headers_in_uitableview_grouped

[image]

All credits go to him for the code.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(20, 2, 320, 30);
    if(section == 0) {
        labelFrame.origin.y = 13;
    }
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.265 green:0.294 blue:0.367 alpha:1.000];
    label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    [containerView addSubview:label];
    return containerView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EITHER**

You need to set `header.frame = CGRectMake(10,1, 100, 18 );`

**OR**

Use Datasource method of `UITableView`

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Header"; // just pass name of your hearder
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 2, 100, 18)];
   label.text= [self.listOfHeader objectAtIndex:section];
   label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
   [view addSubview:label];
   return view;
}
```

And also add

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}
```

Comment: First, 10x. My main goal is to align the text right to left, therefor i do that programmatically, and because of this, i can't use the titleForHeaderInSection. I want to design by hand :/.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it calculate the width of your UILabel dynamically/programmatically. Using this code :

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                        constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                        lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Then add 10 pixle to the width you get. Set the frame of your UILabel. And, set it following way :

```
header.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,5.0,expectedLabelSize.width + 10.0,expectedLabelSize.height);
header.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```